# Java lambda to return a list with duplicated code issue

Tags: java, lambda, spring-data-jpa

I have a question when I tried to get a list by **lambda expression**. The code looks like

```
        Collection<Order> updateOrders = orderCodes.stream().filter(orderCode -> {
            List<String> iccids = new ArrayList<>();
            ShippedOrder shippedOrder = orderMap.get(orderCode);
            iccids.addAll(getSimEsnByShippedOrder(shippedOrder));
            Optional<Order> maybeOrder = orderRepository.findByCode(orderCode);
            
            return maybeOrder.isPresent() && !iccids.isEmpty();

        }).map(orderCode -> {
            List<String> iccids = new ArrayList<>();
            ShippedOrder shippedOrder = orderMap.get(orderCode);
            iccids.addAll(getSimEsnByShippedOrder(shippedOrder));
            Optional<Order> maybeOrder = orderRepository.findByCode(orderCode);
            
            Order order = maybeOrder.get();
            List<String> existedEsnList = order.getEsnList();
            if(!existedEsnList.isEmpty())
                iccids.addAll(existedEsnList);
            order.setEsnList(iccids);
            
            return order;

        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Obviously, a piece of duplicated code is appeared in filter() and map(), and database is accessed 2 times for the same reason. How can I reduce the code? Thanks

Comment: Just make a method for that?

Comment: @dan1st He would still end up calling the method twice.

Comment: Maybe consider using `flatMap`.

Answer (score 0):

First solution could be:

```
    List<String> l = List.of("a", "b", "c");

    l.stream().map((String orderCode)->{
        boolean isOrderPresent = true;
        if(isOrderPresent)
            return orderCode + " order"; //return Order object
        else
            return null;
    })
    .filter(ss-> ss!= null)
    .map((String order) -> {
        System.out.println(order); // else use order.orderCode
        return order;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you can maintain a map of <OrderCode, Order> like this:

```
List<String> l = List.of("a", "b", "c");
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
l.stream().filter((String s)->{
    map.put(s, s+" order");
    return !s.isEmpty();
  })
.forEach((String s) -> {
    System.out.println(map.get(s));  //<== retrieve Orders from local map
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about mapping to null and filtering nulls? It would be something like this:

```
    Collection<Order> updateOrders = orderCodes.stream().map(orderCode -> {
        List<String> iccids = new ArrayList<>();
        ShippedOrder shippedOrder = orderMap.get(orderCode);
        iccids.addAll(getSimEsnByShippedOrder(shippedOrder));
        Optional<Order> maybeOrder = orderRepository.findByCode(orderCode);

        if (maybeOrder.isPresent && !iccids.isEmpty) {
            return getObject(iccids, maybeOrder);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where `getObject`

```
private Object getObject(List<String> iccids, Optional<Order> maybeOrder) {
    Order order = maybeOrder.get();
    List<String> existedEsnList = order.getEsnList();
    if(!existedEsnList.isEmpty())
        iccids.addAll(existedEsnList);
    order.setEsnList(iccids);

    return order;
}
```